# Get source of a shared Facebook post into IFTTT?

Tags: facebook, if-this-then-that

I am trying to figure out a way of getting the source that shared something to Facebook along with content of the post. Ideally I want to export it via RSS, JSON or some other way that will allow me to bring it into IFTTT.

[image: IFTTT post]

This may sound convoluted, but hang with me here. I currently have Twitter sharing to Facebook through IFTTT. I'm primarily a big Twitter user, so I like to share things there first, then cleanly share them to Facebook without any of the Twitter specific syntax (hence why I don't use the official Twitter/FB functionality). This works great as I have it setup. The problem is I want to share links back out of Facebook. Using IFTTT I can get it to share the original source link back out without linking to the Facebook share, which is what I want. The problem is I can't separate things that I might have shared while on Facebook (resharing other users shares) from the Twitter IFTTT shares. They all look the same when they come through to IFTTT. If I shared this way I would end up with a loop of content being shared, which is what I want to avoid.

The one idea I had was to add a hashtag to the Facebook share from IFTTT, but the problem is their functionality works the inverse of this. I can't filter to only share posts without a hashtag, only posts with. I'm not sure if there are any services out there that do this at all. This is something I would have previously cooked up a way to do in Yahoo Pipes, but obviously that isn't viable anymore.